# Anonymous function with spread operator to fill a state object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS I want to fill a list of object with itself adding new elements as a copy of the input object at the end of the list. `array.push();` doesn't work in ReactJS context, so I have to use the spread operator here.

But when I use `setList(list => [...list, e.target]);`, list gets filled with *references* to `e.target`, so changing the object that `e.target` is referring to, changes every entry in `list` as well.

Therefore I wanted to use an anonymous function that returns a copy of the input object and puts it into `list`.

```
function handleEvent(e) {
    console.log("e:", e); //e: Object { target: {…} }

    setList(list => [...list,  function() {
        let obj = e.target;
        let key = 0;

        for(key in obj) {
            copy[key] = obj[key];
        }

        return copy;
    }]);

    console.log("list:", list);
}
```

But this fills `list` with instances of handleEvent functions, not with the contents of `e.target`.

```
list: 
        (2) […]
        ​
        0: function handleEvent()​
        1: function handleEvent()
        ​
        length: 2
        ​
        <prototype>: Array []
```

When I use `setList(list => [...list, copyObj(e.target) {` with a separate, named function, it works but I wanted get used to anonymous functions and thus implement that here.

How do I get my syntax right here?

Comment: _"But this fills list with instances of handleEvent functions"_ - No, it wouldn't.

Comment: But that's what console.log gives.

Comment: Only if `setList` magically replaces the anonymous function with the function it is executed in: https://jsbin.com/buzoheboxu/edit?js,console

Comment: I don't know how ReactJS handles that here. setList is a regular callback function for setState hook: `const [list, setList] = useState([]);`